# sql query repeat

Tags: sql, repeat

My query is like below (not working correctly)

```
SELECT RentACar.dbo.Car.car_id as clm_CAR_ID,
RentACar.dbo.Car_Image.car_image_url as clm_PICTURE_URL,
RentACar.dbo.Users.user_agent_name as clm_USERNAME

from RentACar.dbo.Car

left join RentACar.dbo.Users
on RentACar.dbo.Car.car_user_id = RentACar.dbo.Users.user_id 

left join RentACar.dbo.Car_Image
on RentACar.dbo.Car.car_id = RentACar.dbo.Car_Image.car_image_car_id
```

my aim is that show all the cars at car_table whith user_name of user_table and 
picture_url of image_table.

But at the image_table i have a problem..
a car can has more than a picture.

---

this query results;

```
clm_CAR_ID      clm_PICTURE_URL                                    clm_USERNAME         
1       NULL                                            ac ad
2       NULL                                            ac ad
3       NULL                                            ac ad
4       NULL                                            ac ad
5       /upload/10CeskUntitled23-11.png                                 ac ad
5       /upload/10CveloperDesktopdeskUntitl4ed-11.png                           ac ad
6       NULL                                            ac ad
7       NULL                                            ac ad
8       NULL                                            ac ad
9       /upload/9ngsdeveloperDesktopmelekkım.jpg                                    ac ad
9       /upload/9eskt1opmelekkktc.jpg                                   ac ad
10      /upload/10CeveloperDesktopd2eskxm.jpg                                   ac ad
10      /upload/10ngsdeveloperDesktopdeskxm.jpg                                 ac ad
10      /upload/10sdeveloperDesktopdeskU5ntitled-11.png                         ac ad
```

---

but my expaction result

```
clm_CAR_ID      clm_PICTURE_URL                                    clm_USERNAME         
1       NULL                                            ac ad
2       NULL                                            ac ad
3       NULL                                            ac ad
4       NULL                                            ac ad
5       /upload/10CeskUntitled23-11.png                                 ac ad
6       NULL                                            ac ad
7       NULL                                            ac ad
8       NULL                                            ac ad
9       /upload/9ngsdeveloperDesktopmelekkım.jpg                                    ac ad
10      /upload/10CeveloperDesktopd2eskxm.jpg                                   ac ad
```

Comment: How do you want to handle cars that have more than one image - one row per car per image, one row per car with the first (or last) image for the car, one row per car with all applicable image urls pivoted or concatenated into a single field...? Also, is this SQLServer?

Comment: Can you post what output you are expecting in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not specified which RDBMS you are using I am posting the most generic answer I can come up with:

```
SELECT  Car_ID AS clm_CAR_ID, 
        Car_Image_URL AS clm_PICTURE_URL,
        user_agent_name AS clm_USERNAME
FROM    Car
        INNER JOIN Users
            ON Car_User_ID = User_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  Img.*
            FROM    Car_Image Img
                    INNER JOIN 
                    (   SELECT  MIN(Image_ID) AS Image_ID
                        FROM    Car_Image
                        GROUP BY Car_Image_Car_ID
                    ) AS MaxImg
                        ON MaxImg.Image_ID = Img.Image_ID
        ) AS Img
            ON Img.Car_Image_Car_ID = Car_ID;
```

I have tested this on [This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ba3c/1) and it works for MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL and SQLLite. I have almost no experience with Oracle so was unable to fix the syntax error when testing with Oracle.

Comment: thanks GarethD i try this, but results is wrong :(     

`SELECT  car_id, user_name, car_image_url
FROM    RentACar.dbo.Car
        INNER JOIN RentACar.dbo.Users
            ON car_user_id = user_id
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  Img.*
            FROM    RentACar.dbo.Car_Image Img
                    INNER JOIN 
                    (   SELECT  MAX(car_image_id) AS Image_ID
                        FROM    RentACar.dbo.Car_Image
                        GROUP BY car_image_car_id) AS MaxImg
ON MaxImg.Image_ID = Img.car_image_id) AS Img
 ON Img.car_image_id = car_id`

Comment: Could you give me a clue as to what is wrong with the results? It is pretty difficult to correct something when I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: there are 5 car images at RentACar.dbo.Car. How ever when query is run the program returns only the images of two cars that areid number 6 and 9. but the car, id number 6, has no image..

Comment: Based on what you have put in the answer I cannot see how my solution produces different results to what you are expecting. I have copied your data into [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ba3c/1) and the results of the query are exactly the same as what you have put in your answer.

Comment: Thank you GarethD i edited your post `SELECT car_id AS clm_CAR_ID, car_image_url AS clm_PICTURE_URL, user_agent_name AS clm_USERNAME FROM RentACar.dbo.Car INNER JOIN RentACar.dbo.Users ON car_user_id = user_id LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Img.* FROM RentACar.dbo.Car_Image Img INNER JOIN ( SELECT MIN(car_image_id) AS Image_ID FROM RentACar.dbo.Car_Image GROUP BY car_image_car_id ) AS MaxImg ON MaxImg.Image_ID = Img.car_image_id ) AS Img ON Img.car_image_car_id = car_id;` you are dignitary thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

You should join Car_Table, User_Table.
Then join it with Image_Table that
 contains one photo per car.

```
SELECT car_id, user_name, image_url
FROM
   (Car_Table JOIN User_Table AS cars_and_photos ON car_user_id = user_id) JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM Image_Table GROUP_BY image_car_id) AS one_photo_per_car
ON one_photo_per_car.image_car_id = cars_and_photos.user_id
```

I didn't test this query

Comment: hi Jaroslaw i didnt run this,  
`SELECT RentACar.dbo.Car.car_id, RentACar.dbo.Users.user_agent_name, RentACar.dbo.Car_Image.car_image_url
FROM
(RentACar.dbo.Car JOIN RentACar.dbo.Users ON RentACar.dbo.Car.car_user_id = user_id) AS cars_and_photos 
JOIN
(SELECT * FROM RentACar.dbo.Car_Image GROUP_BY RentACar.dbo.Car_Image.car_image_car_id) AS one_photo_per_car
ON one_photo_per_car.image_car_id = cars_and_photos.user_id` result 
**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'RentACar'.**

Comment: try `SELECT RentACar.dbo.Car.car_id, RentACar.dbo.Users.user_agent_name, RentACar.dbo.Car_Image.car_image_url FROM (RentACar.dbo.Car JOIN RentACar.dbo.Users AS cars_and_photos ON RentACar.dbo.Car.car_user_id = user_id) JOIN (SELECT * FROM RentACar.dbo.Car_Image GROUP BY RentACar.dbo.Car_Image.car_image_car_id) AS one_photo_per_car ON one_photo_per_car.image_car_id = cars_and_photos.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rentacar.dbo.car.car_id, 
       rentacar.dbo.car_image.car_image_url AS image, 
       rentacar.dbo.users.user_agent_name   AS USER 
from rentacar.dbo.car
left join rentacar.dbo.car_image
on rentacar.dbo.car.car_id = rentacar.dbo.car_image.image_car_id
left join rentacar.dbo.users
on rentacar.dbo.car.car_user_id = rentacar.dbo.users.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks Hagbart Celine this has run but,

`SELECT DISTINCT RentACar.dbo.Car.car_id,
RentACar.dbo.Car_Image.car_image_url as Resim,
RentACar.dbo.Users.user_agent_name as Sahip

from RentACar.dbo.Car
left join RentACar.dbo.Car_Image
on RentACar.dbo.Car.car_id = RentACar.dbo.Car_Image.car_image_car_id
left join RentACar.dbo.Users
on RentACar.dbo.Car.car_user_id = RentACar.dbo.Users.user_id `

The program returns number of pictures that have how many cars from Image_Table. I want from this program to return each car only one time